# how to add multiple video Id's for scraping Through YTAPI Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube-data-api, sentiment-analysis

Currently I am providing just 1 video id and getting results I want to add multiple Id's to get results  i.e.

```
api_key ="API_KEY"
**video_id= "d56mG7DezGs"#how do i add multiple Id's?**
resource = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

#create a request to get all the comments on the video
request = resource. commentThreads().list(
                            part="snippet",
                            videoId=video_id,
                            order="relevance")  #top comments.
#execute the request
response =request.execute()

#get first 10 items for 10 comments 
items = response["items"][:5]
```

on this in 1 video

```
Comment By: Programming with Mosh
Coment Text:  Get the complete course (zero to hero): 
Likes on Comment : 12
Comment Date:  2022-05-23T14:54:06Z
**Sentiment(polarity=0.3, subjectivity=0.45)**
```

I just want to add multiple id's to scrapp.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the ids should be separated by commas https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

Comment: i tried this video_id= "d56mG7DezGs","qj-U8XKyxRs" but got this error Exception has occurred: HttpError in this response =request.execute()

Comment: it should be a single string so therefore it should just be `video_id= "d56mG7DezGs,qj-U8XKyxRs"`

Comment: even i tried this "d56mG7DezGs,qj-U8XKyxRs" but still getting same error

Comment: **You have exposed your API key**. Please renew/destroy that key to avoid 3rd party misuse

Answer (score 0):

You can't request the [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId) with multiple video ids:

> **videoId**
>
> **string**
>
> The videoId parameter instructs the API to return comment threads associated with the specified video ID.

So you are obliged to make one request to this endpoint for each video you want to check. Maybe if you precise your workflow (why you want to add multiple video ids), we could help you to optimize it.